# Embed Youtube Player in Smart Tv Alliance App

Tags: youtube-api, smart-tv-alliance

I am developing an app with an embedded Youtube Player for the "Smart Tv Alliance" platform (using the latest SDK @ smarttv-alliance.org).

I am using the iframe-html5 version of the Player APIs and I get the following behavior: the player embed loads in the app simulator, but then there seems to be some problem with video streaming protocols and I always get a "video not available" error message, no matter which Ytb video I load.

Any ideas how to get this to work?

Many thanks. Regards. Nicolò

Answer (score 0):

This may be a problem with the emulator. I've tried the basic iframe sample code Google provides with the API but I got the same results as you. I tried several variations but all I got were 'Unable to post message to http://www.youtube.com' error messages in the console.

I've also tried the sample code on a number of STA compliant TVs here in out lab and it seems to run fine without any problems. So if you have access to an actual device I suggest testing it on there.